# Merge Oracle update both tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING (
          WITH aux AS (
              SELECT
                  a.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                      PARTITION BY a.column3
                      ORDER BY
                          a.column4 DESC
                  ) rn
              FROM
                  table2 a
              WHERE
                  condition
          )
          SELECT
              *
          FROM
              aux
          WHERE
              rn = 1
      )
t2 ON ( join condition )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET t1.column1 = t2.column2,
    t2.column1 = 'X'
WHERE
    conditions;
```

Is it possible to, when matched, not only update columns from table1 but also columns from table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to, when matched, not only update columns from table1 but also columns from table2?

No, it is not possible. You can only update a single table using a `MERGE` statement.